# Reading data from data directory

Tags: mysql, recovery

We have a data directory in MySQL, we want to read data from it. We don't have any username or password and hence is there any method for how can we read the data stored in tables?

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you have complete data directory with all its files non-damaged (correct after-shutdown file state), but there is no installed MySQL (or its instance is damaged and cannot be started)?

Answer (score 2):

The *correct* way to work with *any* database files is through a running instance of [the correct version of] the DBMS that *manages* those files.
Trying to do *anything* manually with database files is, almost always, a "hiding to nothing".
What you're trying to do is akin to finding a car that's been driven at full speed, into a brick wall and *hoping* that you can just hop into it and drive it away.  You have no idea what state those files are in internally - that's the DBMS's job!

Yes, there *are* forensic tools (and companies selling them *and* their services to employ them), but these should be seen a  Last Resort.  You MUST have a proper Recovery Strategy in place, which will give you *lots* more options to recover Data than you currently have.